# make dynamic UIbutton appear and dissapear based on number of items in table view

Tags: swift, uibutton, rx-swift

I'm currently trying to make a dynamic UIbutton appear and disappear based on number of items loaded into a table view, fetched from a backend url. I want to button to appear if there's 12 or more items loaded into the table view and not appear if there's less than 12. Any ideas on the best way to handle this?

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

public class AllProvidersPickerViewController: InputableTableViewController, ViewModelHolder {

    @IBOutlet private(set) weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var dontSeeProviderButton: UIButton!

    var viewModel: AllProvidersPickerViewModel! = nil
    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupRx()
    }

    private func setupRx() {
      viewModel.shownProviders
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "ProviderCell")) { _, mvpd, cell in
            cell.textLabel?.text = mvpd.displayName
        }
        .addDisposableTo(bag)

      tableView
        .rx
        .modelSelected(MVPD.self)
        .bind(to: viewModel.selectedProvider)
        .addDisposableTo(bag)

      searchBar
        .rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .bind(to: viewModel.searchQuery)
        .addDisposableTo(bag)

      dontSeeProviderButton
        .rx.tap
        .bind(to: viewModel.tappedDontSeeProvider)
        .addDisposableTo(bag)
    }
}

private extension MVPD {

    var displayName: String {
        return self.names.first ?? ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XFreire's answers are fine, or you could do:

```
viewModel.shownProviders
    .map { $0.count < 12 }
    .bind(to: dontSeeProviderButton.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Make sure `shownProviders` can handle being subscribed to without having to re-send any network requests or whatever. You might need `shareReplayLatestWhileConnected()` for that.

I have been asked to explain this code... I will do so by breaking it down...

---

```
let shownProviders = viewModel.shownProviders
```

At this point, I know that `shownProviders` is an array. I don't know much about the type that the array contains because that info wasn't in the question, but I don't need to know

```
let shownProviders = viewModel.shownProviders
let shouldHideButton = shownProviders.map { $0.count < 12 }
```

In the above line, I know that `$0` is an array and I know that the button should hide if there are fewer than 12 items in the array. `$0.count < 12` returns a Bool. `map` will transform the `shownProviders` Observable into whatever the block returns, so I know that `shouldHideButton` is an `Observable<Bool>`.

```
let shownProviders = viewModel.shownProviders
let shouldHideButton = shownProviders.map { $0.count < 12 }
let disposable = shouldHideButton.bind(to: dontSeeProviderButton.rx.isHidden)
```

The above line of code binds the result of `shouldHideButton` to the `isHidden` property of the button. It returns a disposable.

```
let shownProviders = viewModel.shownProviders
let shouldHideButton = shownProviders.map { $0.count < 12 }
let disposable = shouldHideButton.bind(to: dontSeeProviderButton.rx.isHidden)
disposable.disposed(by: bag)
```

This last line ensures that the binding will be broken when the view controller goes out of scope.

Comment: Oh yes! I like it :) More elegant!

Comment: Yess! Thank you so much, @Daniel T.! Can you explain the logic behind what's happening here in your own words. I'm still learning RXswift and Swift in general so would like to understand everything completely as i go (:

Comment: There you go. In my own words.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
viewModel.shownProviders
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] items in 
        if items.count < 12 {
            self?.viewAllProvidersButton.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            self?.viewAllProvidersButton.isHidden = false
        }
    })
    .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Other way could be to create a property `buttonVisibilityObserver` of type `AnyObserver` and bind it to `viewModel.shownProviders`. Something like this (not tested):

```
var buttonVisibilityObserver: AnyObserver<[ItemsType]> {

    return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: viewAllProvidersButton) { button, items in
        button.isHidden = items.count < 12 ? true : false

    }.asObserver()
}
```

And then in your `setupRx()`:

```
viewModel.shownProviders
    .bind(to: buttonVisibilityObserver)
    .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Comment: You're brilliant! That absolutely worked! Except i switched out "dontSeeProviderButton" for "viewAllProvidersButton" and put all that in setupRx(). Thanks so much for your help. I'm a newbie and still getting the hang of swift and swift rx.

Comment: `.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] items in                if items.count < 12 {
                    self?.viewAllProvidersButton.isHidden = true
                }
                else {
                    self?.viewAllProvidersButton.isHidden = false
                }
            })
            .addDisposableTo(bag)`

Comment: Great! I am updating the answer to use `viewAllProvidersButton`. If the answer helped, could you please mark it as accepted? :)